# Netezza: Show dates even if 0 data for that day

Tags: netezza

I have this query through an odbc connection in excel for a refreshable report with data for every 4 weeks. I need to show the dates in each of the 4 weeks even if there is no data for that day because this data is then linked to a Graph. Is there a way to do this?

thanks.

```
Select  b.INV_DT, sum( a.ORD_QTY) as Ordered, sum( a.SHIPPED_QTY) as Shipped
    from fct_dly_invoice_detail a, fct_dly_invoice_header b, dim_invoice_customer c
    where a.INV_HDR_SK = b.INV_HDR_SK
    and b.DIM_INV_CUST_SK = c.DIM_INV_CUST_SK
    and a.SRC_SYS_CD = 'ABC'
    and a.NDC_NBR is not null 
    **and b.inv_dt between CURRENT_DATE - 16 and CURRENT_DATE**
    and b.store_nbr in (2851, 2963, 3249, 3385, 3447, 3591, 3727, 4065, 4102, 4289, 4376, 4793, 5209, 5266, 5312, 5453, 5569, 5575, 5892, 6534, 6571, 7110, 9057, 9262, 9652, 9742, 10373, 12392, 12739, 13870
    )
    group by 1
```

Comment: This is my output:                                                                                      INV_DT ORDERED SHIPPED Service Level
4/29/2015 12,078 10,425 86%
4/30/2015 11,496 10,733 93%
5/1/2015 9,841 8,092 82%
5/2/2015 6 6 100%
5/4/2015 13,942 12,664 91%
5/5/2015 15,640 13,594 87%
5/6/2015 11,618 10,255 88%
5/7/2015 15,644 13,114 84%
5/8/2015 9,062 8,033 89%
5/11/2015 13,975 12,879 92%
5/12/2015 12,342 10,211 83%
5/13/2015 11,059 9,450 85%                                              notice I have days missing...i want to show the date even if it is 0 shipped or ordered for the day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general purpose solution to this is to create a date dimension table, and then perform an outer join to that date dimension table on the INV_DT column.

There are tons of good resources you can search for on creating a good date dimension table, so I'll just create a quick and dirty (and trivial) example here. I highly recommend some research in that area if you'll be doing a lot of BI/reporting.

If our table we want to report from looks like this:

```
                Table "TABLEZ"
 Attribute |  Type  | Modifier | Default Value
-----------+--------+----------+---------------
 AMOUNT    | BIGINT |          |
 INV_DT    | DATE   |          |
Distributed on random: (round-robin)

select * from tablez order by inv_dt

 AMOUNT |   INV_DT
--------+------------
      1 | 2015-04-04
      1 | 2015-04-04
      1 | 2015-04-06
      1 | 2015-04-06
(4 rows)
```

and our report looks like this:

```
SELECT inv_dt,
   SUM(amount)
FROM tablez
WHERE inv_dt BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE - 5 AND CURRENT_DATE
GROUP BY inv_dt;

   INV_DT   | SUM
------------+-----
 2015-04-04 |   2
 2015-04-06 |   2
(2 rows)
```

We can create a date dimension table that contains a row for every date (or ate last 1024 days in the past and 1024 days in the future using the _v_vector_idx view in this example).

```
create table date_dim (date_dt date);

insert into date_dim select current_date - idx from _v_vector_idx;
insert into date_dim select current_date + idx +1 from _v_vector_idx;
```

Then our query would look like this:

```
SELECT d.date_dt,
   SUM(amount)
FROM tablez a
   RIGHT OUTER JOIN date_dim d
   ON a.inv_dt = d.date_dt
WHERE d.date_dt BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE -5 AND CURRENT_DATE
GROUP BY d.date_dt;


  DATE_DT   | SUM
------------+-----
 2015-04-01 |
 2015-04-02 |
 2015-04-03 |
 2015-04-04 |   2
 2015-04-05 |
 2015-04-06 |   2
(6 rows)
```

If you actually needed a zero value instead of a NULL for the days where you had no data, you could use a COALESCE or NVL like this:

```
SELECT d.date_dt,
   COALESCE(SUM(amount),0)
FROM tablez a
   RIGHT OUTER JOIN date_dim d
   ON a.inv_dt = d.date_dt
WHERE d.date_dt BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE -5 AND CURRENT_DATE
GROUP BY d.date_dt;


  DATE_DT   | COALESCE
------------+----------
 2015-04-01 |        0
 2015-04-02 |        0
 2015-04-03 |        0
 2015-04-04 |        2
 2015-04-05 |        0
 2015-04-06 |        2
(6 rows)
```

Comment: I'd really like to avoid that type of complicated SQL, I don't want to have to build a date table. can I do something more like a case statement for this? or like:Select  b.INV_DT,  sum(( a.ORD_QTY),0) as Ordered, sum(( a.SHIPPED_QTY),0) as Shipped

Comment: This is a case where you can't have your cake and eat it too. If you want to keep the SQL simple, you need a date dimension table. If you don't want a date dimension table you will need to generate the date rows programmatically every time, which is more complicated. A CASE expression will let you tweak values in a row, but it's not going to let you create rows for the dates that aren't in your table.

Comment: You can't avoid using a dimension table (or otherwise a range of dates) because your transaction table doesn't have data for the missing dates. Using a date table (date dimension) is the best practice and most used technique for this type of queries, and has been for many years and will be for many years to come. It's simpler (and usually faster) than any alternative.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help. I guess I better figure out how to do this!

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @ScottMcG that you need to get the list of dates. However if you are in a situation where you aren't allowed to create a table.  You can simplify things.   All you need is a table that has at least 28 rows.  Using your example, this should work.

```
select date_list.dt_nm, nvl(results.Ordered,0) as Ordered, nvl(results.Shipped,0) as Shipped
from
(select row_number() over(order by sub.arb_nbr)+ (current_date -28) as dt_nm
from (select rowid as arb_nbr
from fct_dly_invoice_detail b
limit 28) sub ) date_list left outer join


( Select  b.INV_DT, sum( a.ORD_QTY) as Ordered, sum( a.SHIPPED_QTY) as Shipped
    from fct_dly_invoice_detail a inner join
     fct_dly_invoice_header b
         on     a.INV_HDR_SK = b.INV_HDR_SK
                and a.SRC_SYS_CD = 'ABC'
                and a.NDC_NBR is not null
                 **and b.inv_dt between CURRENT_DATE - 16 and CURRENT_DATE**
                     and b.store_nbr in (2851, 2963, 3249, 3385, 3447, 3591, 3727, 4065, 4102, 4289, 4376, 4793, 5209, 5266, 5312, 5453, 5569, 5575, 5892, 6534, 6571, 7110, 9057, 9262, 9652, 9742, 10373, 12392, 12739, 13870)
         inner join
     dim_invoice_customer c
    on b.DIM_INV_CUST_SK = c.DIM_INV_CUST_SK
    group by 1 ) results

on date_list.dt_nm = results.inv_dt
```